# Sympy lambdify how to write f(x1,x2, x3,....xn)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I am trying to use lambdify. The code is:

```
expr = x+y
f = lambdify((x,y), expr, "numpy")
```

Now evaluate the function, for example: f(1,2)
if the x, y input is stored in a list, like [1,2] how can I pass the variable to the function f? assuming that f can be a function of thousand variables so manually input is not ideal.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Does `f(*[1, 2])` work?  If so, then you could do `args = [1, 2]` then `f(*args)`.

Comment: that is great! it works! Thanks alot.